# Datagrid row background color bind to property in individual item from data source collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF and I want to bind the BackgrounColor of the rows to a property to individual items in the collection that I am providing as the ItemsSource to the datagrid.

```
   public class Log: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _timestamp;
    private string _threadName;
    private string _userName;
    private string _message;
    private Brush _backgroundColor;

    public string Timestamp
    {
        get { return _timestamp; }
        set
        {
            if (_timestamp == value) return;
            _timestamp = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Timestamp");
        }
    }
    public string ThreadName
    {
        get { return _threadName; }
        set
        {
            if (_threadName == value) return;
            _threadName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ThreadName");
        }
    }
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set
        {
            if (_userName == value) return;
            _userName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            if (_message == value) return;
            _message = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }

    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return _backgroundColor; }
        set
        {
            if (_backgroundColor== value) return;
            _backgroundColor = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor");
        }
    }


    public bool IsCustomLog = false;
    public string HighlightColor = null;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //Constructor
    public Log(string timestamp, string threadName, string userName, string message, Brush backgroundColor)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Timestamp = timestamp;
        ThreadName = threadName;
        Message = message;
        BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    //Methods
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And I am trying to bind the BackgroundColor of the datagrid row to the BackgroundColor property in the Log class.

I try to bind it like this:

```
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CCCCCC"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

But it does not set the background color. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a typo in your code since `_backgroundColor` is `Brush` while `BackgroundColor` is `string`:

```
public string BackgroundColor
{
    get { return _backgroundColor; }
    set
    {
        if (_backgroundColor== value) return;
        _backgroundColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor");
    }
}
```

I suggest you to make the `BackgroundColor` a `Color` since the 'Color' postfix of your property name, and change the 'Setter' in XAML like this:

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
</Setter>
```